# PHP get item x through the end of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some PHP code (written by someone else) that's parsing a html file and getting the 7th item in an array from that file.
That item is supposed to be the last item in the array.

The problem is that that item sometimes has a comma within the string, and in that case, the code only gets the first part of the string, since it thinks the end of the item is a new item in the array.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
$read = fread($open,200);
$text = explode(",",$read);
$msg = $text[6];
$text = ($msg);
```

Is there any way to have it get the 7th item until the end of the array, instead of just the 7th item, and return it as one item?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it's actually getting the 7th element (0-5 = 6 elements, [6] = 7th element)

```
$msg = implode(array_slice($text,5));
```

Comment: So that should get from the 6th item to the end?

Comment: Looks like the split function may be deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 - any alternatives?

Comment: I mean `array_slice` - mistyped it. Fixed. That should get it from the 6th element to the end (changed it to start at [5] as well).

Comment: slice on 6, from the question: `7th item until the end of the array`

Comment: So if I want it to start at the 7th element (I made a mistake earlier and went back and edited it, I did want the 7th element), I just change the 5 to a 6, right?
Thanks!!

Comment: [sigh] Then change the 5 to a 6 in your code - do I really have to edit the answer and do that for you?

Comment: Also, just realizing that this will delete the comma in the last item - any way to keep that in there?

Comment: The comma is your delimiter - it's not supposed to be in there. The `implode()` added the data after that comma (apparently a blank in your case). If you want to append a comma: `$msg .= ',';` after the code.

Comment: @IsaacL $msg=implode(',', array_slice($text,6));

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - will that add a comma in where the comma was originally, and and only if there is a comma in the string?

Answer (score 3):

Use array_slice to get everything from array element 6 to the end of the array, then implode the result.

Comment: I'm not so good with writing code - is the code below basically what you had in mind?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! Guess you really answered it- I just couldn't piece that together myself... ;)